# Visual Studio: 2 projects in 1 solution. How to start project 2 from project 1?

Tags: python, c#, projects-and-solutions

Noob here! Hey! I'll tell everything in details now. I have 2 projects in 1 solution. [2 in 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMY5P.png). The C# one is main of 2 and working with my postgres database. The second one is a Python app where the trained model predicts a number from a given image (0-9). The problem is I need to start python app from C# and idc how to do it. From what I found in Visual I can launch only c# or only python app or both of them at the same time but not one from another. The best thing would be if I could launch python app by clicking button 10 in my c# [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tKJi.png). I'd send a path to img to python from c# and python would return me (back to c# app) the pridicted number. I only need to know how to launch python from c# (and if its possible how to send him a path to img).

Idk what to try, described everything in the problem

Comment: It sounds like you want your C# application to run another process. You may want to look at the [`Process` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Try [Debugging Multiple Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes). Apparently, there's a "Multiple startup projects" Solution-Property that you can use when configuring start-up of the debugger.